# Validation description in angular2 forms validators

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Looking through the angular2 api Control class I see

```
minLength(minLength: number) : Function
```

I understand what the function does.

I was wondering though if a description of what went wrong when the validation fails could not be placed right there in the function.

For instance, I am wondering if the function could not be

```
minLength(minLength: number, description: string) : Function
```

Where the description describes the reason for the error as shown below

```
Control firstCtrl = new Control( '', Validators.minLength(2, description: 'Minium of two characters required) );
```

I have not been able to find any similar validators in the API. If one exist I would be happy if a link/explanation could be shared.

Looking forward to seeing your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no [builtin Validators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/validators.ts) that take an extra parameter for an error description. But for that you can write your own.

Let's take for example the builtin `minLength` validator. We add a second parameter called *desc* that'll hold the custom error message.

```js
class CustomValidators {
  static minLengthWithDescription(minLength: number, desc: string): Function {
    return (control: modelModule.Control): {[key: string]: any} => {
      return v.length < minLength ?
        {"minlength": {
             "requiredLength": minLength, 
             "actualLength": v.length, 
             "desc": desc // Here we pass our custom error message
        }
      } : null;
    };
  }
}
```

As you see we barely touched the original one. Now it's as simple as checking in our View if the error message exists

```js
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
  <p>
    Year: <input ngControl="year"> 

    // We use the Elvis operator to check if the error exists or not
    // if exists it will print the error message
    {{myForm.controls.year.getError('minlength')?.desc}}
  </p>
</form>
```

And finally we set the error message we want to show

```js
export class App {
    year: Control = new Control('', 
        CustomValidators.minLengthWithDescription(4, 'Wrong ammount of numbers'));
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3c5ecwUP3IUT0Bv91bik?p=preview) with an example working.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I think you should submit your solution as an issue. Certainly just adding a description as the error message is better than what exist now.

Comment: Where is the `modelModule.Control` coming from. I use Dart so I am trying to port the validator to Dart. I cannot find a reference to modelModule in the example or in the plnkr demo.

Comment: missing a line `var v: string = control.value;` (from your plunker).